# here using ajax i am click the forget button and sending mail to particular email using codeigniter

Tags: html, ajax, codeigniter

**here using ajax i am click the forget button and sending mail to particular email ,but i am getting the error Fail what is the problem i am not getting please any one help me below i shown form and controller**

**Form**

```
<div class="field-wrap">
    <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control inputstyle" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
</div>
<!--<div id='errorDiv' class='col-xs-12 pull-right'> </div>-->
<div class="field-wrap">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="inputstyle" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"/>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>  

</div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-show-forgot").click(function () {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            //  var password= $("#password").val();


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>" + "index.php/Login_cntrl/sendmail",
                data: {email: email},
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert('Successfully send a mail');
                },
                error: function ()
                {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function sendmail() {


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email or number', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login');
        } else {

            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');

            $findemaill = $this->Login_model->getUserInfoByEmail($data['email']);



            if (!empty($findemaill)) {
               // $this->Login_model->getUserInfo('$id');
               // $this->session->set_userdata('forgot_password_flag', 'yes');
                $emailTo = $this->input->post('email');
                   $this->session->set_userdata('findemaill',  $emailTo);
                  //  $this->session->userdata('findemaill');

                $data['result'] = $this->Login_model->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);
                $id = $data['result']->id;
                $this->session->set_userdata('idd', $id);



                $six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

                $this->session->set_userdata('otp', $six_digit_random_number);

                $this->load->model('Login_model');

                $pass['pass'] = $this->Login_model->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);

                $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

                $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

                $config['smtp_port'] = '465';

                $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

                $config['smtp_user'] = 'tworkreport@gmail.com';

                $config['smtp_pass'] = '8722248936';

                $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

                $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

                $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html

                $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

                $this->email->initialize($config);
                $this->email->from('tworkreport@gmail.com', 'Terasukhintrade');
                $this->email->to($emailTo);


                $this->email->subject('Reset your password');

                $body=$this->load->view('forgotmailer',$data,TRUE);

                $this->email->message('Use the following OTP to reset password '.$body );

                $this->email->send();

                echo $this->email->print_debugger();

                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', ' Email address not found!');
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: remove the smtp credentials, make them confidential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using ajax you always needs to return value. You can not use `$this->load->view('login');`

also in ajax function needs to be altered given below.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>" + "index.php/Login_cntrl/sendmail",
            data: {'email': email},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Successfully send a mail');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

public function sendmail() {

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email or number', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {

        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');

        $findemaill = $this->Login_model->getUserInfoByEmail($data['email']);



        if (!empty($findemaill)) {
           // $this->Login_model->getUserInfo('$id');
           // $this->session->set_userdata('forgot_password_flag', 'yes');
            $emailTo = $this->input->post('email');
               $this->session->set_userdata('findemaill',  $emailTo);
              //  $this->session->userdata('findemaill');

            $data['result'] = $this->Login_model->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);
            $id = $data['result']->id;
            $this->session->set_userdata('idd', $id);



            $six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

            $this->session->set_userdata('otp', $six_digit_random_number);

            $this->load->model('Login_model');

            $pass['pass'] = $this->Login_model->forgot_pass_retrive($emailTo);

            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

            $config['smtp_port'] = '465';

            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

            $config['smtp_user'] = 'tworkreport@gmail.com';

            $config['smtp_pass'] = '8722248936';

            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

            $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html

            $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->from('tworkreport@gmail.com', 'Terasukhintrade');
            $this->email->to($emailTo);


            $this->email->subject('Reset your password');

            $body=$this->load->view('forgotmailer',$data,TRUE);

            $this->email->message('Use the following OTP to reset password '.$body );

            $this->email->send();

            echo $this->email->print_debugger();

            $data['is_data'] = '1';
            $data['msg'] = 'Successfully send a mail';
            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {

            $data['is_data'] = '0';
            $data['msg'] = 'Email address not found!';
            echo json_encode($data);

        }

    }
}
```